# (redux) Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: result.map is not a function or its return value is not iterable

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I am trying to build a query in redux toolkit for  fetch and filter search . but i get this error in my console

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: result.map is not a function or its return value is not iterable

here is my code

```
  getSearchByValue: builder.query({
        // Will make a request like https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/bulbasaur
        query: (value) => `/search?q=${value}`,
        providesTags: (result, err, args) =>
        result
          ? [{ type: 'Post', value: 'LIST' }, ...result.map(({ value }) => ({ type: 'Post', value }))]
          : [{ type: 'Post', value: 'LIST' }],
```

and here is my post file

```
const Posts = ({ value }) => {
  
  const { data: posts, isLoading } =   useGetSearchByValueQuery
  (value, {
    
      refetchOnMountOrArgChange: true,
    });
    
      const [filteredPosts, setFilteredPosts] = useState([]);

    

useEffect(() => {
    setFilteredPosts(posts?.filter(post => post.title.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())));
  }, [value, posts]);

  return isLoading ? (
    <LoadingSpinner />
  ) : (
    filteredPosts && <Postsabc posts={filteredPosts} enableImages={false} />
  );
};

  const Wrapper = tw.div`bg-blue`;

export default Posts;
```

value is search value that people type in search bar

i tried many ways but i could not understand

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're seeing suggests that the result value in your providesTags function is not an array and therefore does not have a map method. This could happen if the request to the /search endpoint returns a non-array value or if there is an error in the request.

To debug this issue, you can start by logging the result value in your providesTags function to see what type of value it is. You can also add a catch block to your query to log any errors that might be occurring.

**your code should be like this that includes these changes:**

```js
getSearchByValue: builder.query({
  query: (value) => `/search?q=${value}`,
  providesTags: (result, error, args) => {
    console.log('result:', result);
    if (error) {
      console.error(error);
      return [{ type: 'Post', value: 'LIST' }];
    }
    if (result) {
      return [
        { type: 'Post', value: 'LIST' },
        ...result.map(({ value }) => ({ type: 'Post', value })),
      ];
    }
    return [{ type: 'Post', value: 'LIST' }];
  },
})
```

By logging the result value and checking for errors, you should be able to identify the root cause of the issue and make any necessary changes to your code

Comment: You should have issue in sending data from your custom hook, check again the data you fetched again and be sure that are running map on an array

Comment: i saw picture of data that you sent , you should map on "products" instead of results